# How can I change all pixel values of a portion of an image to a certain value?

Tags: image-processing

Consider an image (`img`) as

[image]

What is the best way to convert all the pixel values to say, `0.8`?

**Edit 1** Let me explain my objective. Firstly, I partition the image into 4 parts.

```
{width, height} = ImageDimensions[img];
Flatten@ImagePartition[img, {225/2, 225/2}];
```

Now I want to change the pixel values of the first image part to be `0.8` and then merge all the parts together. One thing to be noted here is that I don't have the information about the pixel values in the parts and all the pixels may not have the same value.

One issue in changing the pixel value in the part image is that it may create artifacts in the boundary while merging them together after changing pixel value. Therefore, I need a way such that there be a mapping between the first part and the corresponding portion in the original image so that I can make the changes directly on the image instead on the part.

**Edit 2** I have applied image partitioning to treat individual parts as blocks so that I can compare the blocks with its neighbor to set the condition for changing the pixel value in a block.

Comment: Maybe `img = Image[ConstantArray[0.8, ImageDimensions[img][[{-1, 1}]]]]`

Comment: @Majis:  Why do you want to "convert" pixel values rather than merely defining a new array having the desired pixel value?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork see my edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MapAt` can be used:

```
MapAt[ImageAdd[ImageMultiply[#, 0], 0.8] &,
   ImagePartition[img, {225/2, 225/2}], {1, 1}]
```

[image]

Comment: This is done on the partitioned image. I want it to be applied directly to the original image.

Answer (score 2):

not sure why you want to do the partitioning. `ReplacePixelValue` can do it direct.

```
img = ImageResize[ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Mandrill"}], 100]
ReplacePixelValue[img, {1 ;; 50, 1 ;; 50} -> Hue[.3]]
```

[image]

actually partitioning proves to be considerably faster..

```
part = ImagePartition[img, {50, 50}];
ImageAssemble[
 MapAt[Image[ConstantArray[Hue[.3], ImageDimensions[#]]] &, 
  part , {2, 1}]]
```

Comment: I know. Here you need to specify the range. By partition, I want to specify the block where the changing is to be done.

Comment: see edit. Partitioning turns out to be faster anyway.

Answer (score 1):

The two functions it sounds like you want to use are `ImageApply` and `ImageApplyIndexed`.

Let's make a random base image:

`baseIm = RandomImage[];`

Now, we want to turn the right half to 0.8-valued pixels.

`ImageApply` will get all of them. To choose, we build a mask image.

`mask = ImageAssemble[{ConstantImage[0, {75, 150}], ConstantImage[1, {75, 150}]}];`

Now, we can turn every pixel selected by the mask to 0.8 (or apply whatever function we want to it):

`ImageApply[0.8 &, baseIm, Masking -> mask]`

[image: A random image with the right half all converted to take 0.8 value.]

If we already know which pixels we want and don't want to go to the trouble of building a mask, we can use `ImageApplyIndexed`, which gives position as an argument to our function.

Let's make a random base image:

`baseIm = RandomImage[];`

Now we apply a function that makes the pixel value 0.8 if we are to the right or below the mid-lines:

`ImageApplyIndexed[If[#2[[1]] > 75 && #2[[2]] > 75, 0.8, #1] &, baseIm]`

[image: A random image with pixels in quadrant 4 converted to 0.8 value.]